# Cocoapod "pod spec lint" CompileSwift returned an unsuccessful exit code

Tags: swift, xcode, sqlite, cocoapods

I'm trying to create my first Cocoapod and I've set up my pod just fine so far, however when I try to lint or push, I get a bunch of build errors.
The pod which contains swift code utilizes the sqlite3 library.
I've linked it to the build phase of the Xcode pod project and I can build fine from there, but when running `pod repo push` on my pod, it tries to build and fails with a bunch of "use of unresolved identifier" errors, presumably from not having the dependency.
I have also added `s.library = 'sqlite3'` in my podspec file but no luck.

Here is a snippet

```
- ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  SQLift/SQLift/Classes/PreparedStatement.swift:51:16: error: value of type 'String' has no member 'isValid'
- ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  SQLift/SQLift/Classes/PreparedStatement.swift:61:16: error: use of unresolved identifier 'sqlite3_bind_null'
- ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  SQLift/SQLift/Classes/PreparedStatement.swift:61:55: error: use of unresolved identifier 'SQLITE_OK'
- ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  SQLift/SQLift/Classes/PreparedStatement.swift:62:41: error: use of unresolved identifier 'sqlite3_errmsg'
- ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  SQLift/SQLift/Classes/PreparedStatement.swift:67:16: error: use of unresolved identifier 'sqlite3_bind_int'
- ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  SQLift/SQLift/Classes/PreparedStatement.swift:67:76: error: use of unresolved identifier 'SQLITE_OK'
- ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  SQLift/SQLift/Classes/PreparedStatement.swift:68:41: error: use of unresolved identifier 'sqlite3_errmsg'
- ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  SQLift/SQLift/Classes/PreparedStatement.swift:73:16: error: use of unresolved identifier 'sqlite3_bind_text'
- ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  SQLift/SQLift/Classes/PreparedStatement.swift:73:95: error: use of unresolved identifier 'SQLITE_OK'
- ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  SQLift/SQLift/Classes/PreparedStatement.swift:74:41: error: use of unresolved identifier 'sqlite3_errmsg'
- ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  SQLift/SQLift/Classes/PreparedStatement.swift:79:16: error: use of unresolved identifier 'sqlite3_bind_double'
```

I'm still new to creating pods and I'm not too sure how to fix this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `--no-clean` option to the `pod spec lint` command to get an Xcode workspace in which you can reproduce and debug the build issue.

Comment: Looking at the resulting workspace I noticed it was missing some imports I had added later. At that point I realized that the lint pulls the sources from the defined url in the podspec file rather than the working directory. I pushed my changes, tagged it and it worked. Thanks a lot!